# Enums as string and Data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am struggling to find the best practice for using enums in .NET. (my first project )

I want to create a route method that receives a FromBody argument related to a model that uses an enum. The user input will be a string representation of the enum, and the data saved in the database will also be in string format.

Let's illustrate with some code.

Enum.cs

```
public enum AccountType
{
    PERSONAL,
    BUSINESS
}
```

ModelDTO.cs

```
public class AccountOpenRequestDto
{
    [EnumDataType(typeof(AccountType), ErrorMessage = "Account Status must be 'PERSONAL' or 'BUSINESS'")]
    public AccountType AcctTp { get; set; }

    public Guid? PrntAcctId { get; set; }
}
```

Account.cs

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid AcctId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public AccountType AcctTp { get; set; }
}
```

Now the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OpenAccount([FromBody] AccountOpenRequestDto request){
    var account = new Account() { AcctId=Guid.NewGuid(), AcctTp=request.accType };
}
```

In program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    
});
```

So, right now it works almost as I want:

It allows the user input to be the string representation of the enum as expected.
It validates it to be a value of the enum.
It allows me to save the string representation of the enum in the database and not just the number.
The only issue is that the validation happens before the data annotation in the AccountOpenRequestDto, which means it doesn't show my error message.

It took me some days to get to this solution, and it's still not perfect.

What is the best practice for this scenario?
How can I ensure that my custom error message is thrown when the enum value is invalid?
I prefer a global solution because I have a lot of enums in this project.